# How do I make firefox hello recognize my usb webcam?

Tags: usb, firefox, 14.10, webcam

I have a labtec usb webcam. It works well with cheese. It doesn't work with firefox hello.

`lsusb` output

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 093a:2626 Pixart Imaging, Inc.
```

Comment: Check that your camera isn't blocked as described here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hello-cant-access-my-camera-or-microphone

Comment: Its not blocked. I used this page and there's no video: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need to add a rule to allow the detected device to operate

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules
```

alternately you can use gedit or vim

ADD this piece of text with the appropriate bus, Vendor ID and Device ID
and your hardware will be up and running.. You can enable the rules yourselves or you may want to reboot..

Comment: what piece of text? I can only see an edit command in your post...